# Storing thread in vector member variable triggers breakpoint

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector

I have a class called Executor with a vector<thread*> as a member variable. the submit(const std::function<void()>& f) member function is supposed to start the passed lambda as a thread and add it to the vector. The destructor joins all threads stored in the vector.
The first lambda prints the result, but after that my code runs into a breakpoint somehow.
What am I doing wrong?

here is my code for Executor.h:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
class Executor
{
protected:
    vector<thread*> threads;
    mutex m;
public:
    void submit(const std::function<void()>& f);
    Executor();
    ~Executor();
};
```

Executor.cpp:

```
#include "Executor.h"

void Executor::submit(const std::function<void()>& f)
{
    
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        thread t(f);
        
        threads.push_back(&t);
    }
    
}

Executor::Executor() {}

Executor::~Executor()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++)
    {
        threads.at(i)->join();
        delete threads.at(i);
    }
    threads.clear();
}
```

And main():

```
Executor ex;
        auto fact = [](){cout<< "factor(55) = " << factor(55); };
        auto pk = [](){cout << "P2(100, 50) = " << P2(100, 50); };
        auto fib = [](){cout << "fibonacci(45) = " << fibonacci(45); };


        ex.submit(fact);
        ex.submit(pk);
        ex.submit(fib);
```

Comment: You can't store a pointer to a local variable

Comment: Why do you have a vector of _pointers_ to threads? This does not make any sense. Create a vector of thread objects themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `threads.push_back(&t);` the pointer `&t` is only valid until the end of the scope which `t` is declared in. This causes 3 problems:

1. At the end of the scope inside `submit` the thread is destructed without calling `join` causing `std::terminate` to be called
2. In the destructor of `Executor` `->join` is called on a dangling pointer
3. In the destructor of `Executor` you call `delete` on something that wasn't allocated with `new`

There is no need to use pointers in this code, if you store your threads directly in the vector your code will be simpler and safer:

```
class Executor
{
protected:
    vector<thread> threads;
    mutex m;
public:
    void submit(const std::function<void()>& f);
    Executor();
    ~Executor();

    Executor(const Executor&) = delete;
    Executor& operator=(const Executor&) = delete;
};

void Executor::submit(const std::function<void()>& f)
{  
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        threads.emplace_back(f);
    }   
}

Executor::Executor() {}

Executor::~Executor()
{
    for (auto& thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }
    threads.clear();
}
```

Note I've also deleted the copy constructor and assignment operator to comply with the  [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)